# Why no byte strings in .net / c#?

Tags: c#, string, arrays

Is there a good reason that .NET provides string functions (like search, substring extraction, splitting, etc) only for UTF-16 and not for byte arrays? I see many cases when it would be easier and much more efficient to work with 8-bit chars instead of 16-bit.

Let's take MIME (.EML) format for example. It's basically 8-bit text file. You cannot read it properly using ANY encoding (because encoding info is contained within the file, moreover, different parts can have different encodings).

So you basically better read a MIME file as bytes, determine it's structure (ideally, using 8bit-string parsing tools), and after finding encodings for all encoding-dependent data blocks apply encoding.GetString(data) to get normal UTF-16 representation of them.

Another thing is with base64 data blocks (base64 is just an example, there are also UUE and others). Currently .NET expects you to have a base64 16-bit string but it's not effective to read data of double size and do all conversions from bytes to string just to decode this data. When dealing with megabytes of data, it becomes important.

Missing byte string manipulation functions leads to the need to write them manually but the implementation is obviously less efficient than native code implementation of string functions.

I don't say it needs to be called 8-bit chars, let's keep it bytes. Just have a set of native methods which reflect most string manipulation routines, but with byte arrays. Is this needed only by me or am I missing something important about common .NET architecture?

Comment: The reason they don't exist is the reason for your question, and the same reason you cannot interpret a `MIME (.EML)` file directly: `strings` have no *default* encoding. The developer is expected to know the encoding of the string in the data document, and properly interface with it in that manner. Providing an 8-bit string that has no encoding is no longer a string, it is a sequence of bytes.

Comment: Are you looking for particular methods? There are plenty of methods in `Array`/`List` that cover some of the manipulations, plus LINQ gives you more.

Comment: I don't even say they should be called strings. It's still byte arrays. Forget encodings. Just as you, let's say, have string.IndexOf, have Array.IndexOf(byte[], byte[]).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov
    byte[] a = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdef");
    byte[] b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("bcde");
    int n = Array.IndexOf(a, b);
This won't work. Maybe you meant something else that I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, there is no "position of subrstring" for arrays. .Net framework does not have fast implementation of `IndexOf` anyway, so it is not big loss - and trivial to write one that matches .Net one... It is harder to pick good default algorithm for byte arrays (that tend to be long) compared to string searches (that often used for single word/sentence) - the fact that *you* want to use them for short searches does not mean it is *ok to optimize* for such usage...

Answer (score 1):

> Let's take MIME (.EML) format for example. It's basically 8-bit text file. You cannot read it properly using ANY encoding. (because encoding info is contained within the file, moreover, different parts can have different encodings).

So, you're talking about a case where general-purpose byte-string methods aren't very useful, and you'd need to specialise.

And then for other cases, you'd need to specialise again.

And again.

I actually think byte-string methods would be more useful than your example suggests, but it remains that a lot of cases for them have specialised needs that differ from other uses in incompatible ways.

Which suggests it may not be well-suited for the base library. It's not like you can't make your own that do fit those specialised needs.

Comment: Yes! Possibility to support one particular narrow use case does not immediately mean that feature must be added to a framework.

Comment: I just didn't thought it's so narrow case. What about base64? It's very popular (doesn't seem a special case to me) in apps and currently requires the caller to read it as a string first (applying heavy Encoding transformations) just to get the bytes then. Add memory overhead.

Or are you implying that native implementations of such functions would still be not so faster than managed version?

My main concern was that managed versions would be much slower than if they existed in the core.

Comment: Most of the core is managed too. I don't see why I would have to read a base-64 stream as a string first, I'd work on the binary stream from using `CryptoStream` with `FromBase64Transform`, but just what I'd do with those bytes would depend again on what they were used for.

Comment: Indeed, although for me this class (even its namespace - System.Security.Cryptography) suggests it's for really special purposes. Compare with System.Convert.FromBase64String. FromBase64Transform is actually quite general-purpose but it's hard to find that out just from reading the docs where they mention it's for dealing CryptoStream only.

Comment: I agree. A better choice IMO would have been to more clearly have the transforming of streams delivered by IO classes, and the cases where it is cryptography-related have the transformation provided by classes in security-related namespaces, then the base-64 related conversions wouldn't be somewhere you wouldn't look for them if you weren't doing crypto.

Answer (score 0):

Code to deal with mixed-encoding string manipulation is unnecessarily hard and much harder to explain/get right. The way you suggest to handle mixed encoding every "string" would need to keep encoding information in it and framework would have to provide implementations of all possible combinations of encodings.

Standard solution for such problem is to provide well defined way convert all types to/from single "canonical" representation and perform most operations on that canonical type. You see that more easily in image/video processing where random incoming formats converted into one format tool knows about, processed and converted back to original/any other format.

.Net strings are almost there with "canonical" way to represent Unicode string. There are still many ways to represent same string from user point of view that is actually composed from different `char` elements. Even regular string comparison is huge problem (as frequently in addition to encoding there are locale differences).

Notes

- there are already plenty of API dealing with byte arrays to compare/slice - both in `Array`/`List` classes and as LINQ helpers. The only real missing part is regex-like matches.
- even dealing with single type of encoding for strings (UTF-16 in .Net, UTF-8 in many other systems) is hard enough - even getting "sting length" is a problem (do you need to count surrogate pairs only or include all combining characters, or just `.Length` is enough).
- it is good idea to try to write code yourself to see where complexity come from and whether particular framework decision makes sense. Try to implement 10-15 common `string` functions to support several encodings - i.e. (UTF8, UTF16, and one of 8-bit encoding).

Comment: I'm not saying the framework must keep mixed encoding info in strings. No-no. Just a  tool to deal with byte arrays in a convenient manner. The rest will do the app code.